# Grid column autocollapse

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls

Is it possible for a grid column to collapse itself according to his child width? and the column next to him to expend and take the extra space he got ?

If not, whats the best way to achieve this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the widht of the first `GridColumnDefinition` to Auto and the second one to `*`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        

</Grid>
```